# SQL select Top x records for two columns

Tags: sql-server

I have a table like this

```
ProjectID    PhaseID   Comment     CommentDate
 1             1        a           2/15/2014
 1             1        b           5/1/2014
 1             2        c           8/15/2014
 1             2        d           1/1/2015
 2             1        e           1/21/2014
 2             2        f           5/15/2014
 2             2        g           1/1/2015
```

How do I get the lastest (Top 1) comment for each project for each phase?  For example, for Project 1, phase 1, I should get "b" and "5/1/2014"

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select ProjectID,PhaseID,Comment,CommentDate from 
(select row_number() over(partition by Project_ID,PhaseID order by CommentDate desc) as rn,* from table) a 
where a.rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This type of query works best when there's an identity column (and values are always inserted in order) but this should get you what you need assuming there's no overlapping commentDates

```
select t.*
from table t
inner join (
    SELECT max(commentDate) as maxDate,
        phaseId,
        projectId
    FROM table
    group by phaseId, projectId
) maxComments on t.phaseId = maxComments.phaseId
   and t.projectId = maxComments.projectId
   and t.commentDate = maxComments.maxDate
```

Comment: I just made a simple version for the question.  In reality, there are two tables involved.  Thank you for the answer!